# How can i tune this select statement to prevent it from having select from same table many times?

Tags: sql, oracle, query-performance

I need to tune this sql statement provided by developer, how can I speed it up and prevent the `HAVING` part from select from same users table many time?

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT t.*, ROWNUM pageination__row__123__
    FROM (
        SELECT *
        FROM (
            SELECT SUM(rcm) sum_rcm, SUM(real_amount) sum_ra, MIN(min_share) min_share, MAX(max_share) max_share, SUM(DECODE(rcm_flag, 'Y', 0, rcm)) rcm_n, b.parentid
            FROM bet_total b
            WHERE draw_date BETWEEN :1 AND :2
            GROUP BY parentid
            HAVING (
                parentid
                IN (
                    SELECT id FROM users u2,
                    (
                        SELECT u3.path
                        FROM users u3
                        WHERE u3.type = 2 AND u3.lv = 1 AND u3.tesing = 0 AND u3.user_key = :3
                    ) q
                    WHERE u2.path BETWEEN q.path AND q.path || chr(to_number('FFFFFFFF', 'xxxxxxxx')) AND u2.type = 2
                ) AND SUM(rcm) > :4
            )
        ) b1, users u5
        WHERE (b1.parentid = u5.id AND rcm_n > 0 )
        ORDER BY u5.path
    ) t
) t
WHERE t.pageination__row__123__ <= :5;
```

SQL Execution Plan

[image: SQL Execution Plan]

Index of the table Bet_total

[image: Index of the table Bet_total]

Index of table users
[image: Index of table users]

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Is there a way you can put line breaks/indents in the code without changing its basic function?

Comment: @Onana . . . Provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of the logic, and the schema of the tables being used (types and indexes are important for optimization).  You should also learn to use proper, explicit, **standard** `JOIN` syntax.

Comment: Please post the execution plan as formatted text, not as a (hardly readable) screen shot

Answer (score -1):

You could try using the WITH-Clause.